# C++ Array of pointers to class names

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'd like to be able to hold an array of class names and simply pass an index to a function which would create an instance of a certain class. I have memory constraints so I'd like to not simply create an array of objects.

Here's my most descriptive pseudo-code:

Classes:

```
class Shape
{
public:
    Shape();
};

class Square : public Shape
{
public:
    Square();
};

class Triangle : public Shape
{
public:
    Triangle();
};
```

Main:

```
int main()
{
    pointerToShapeClass arrayOfShapes[2];       // incorrect syntax - but
    arrayOfShapes[0] = pointerToSquareClass;    // how would i do this?
    arrayOfShapes[1] = pointerToTriangleClass;

    cin << myNumber;

    // Depending on input, create instance of class corresponding to array index
    if (myNumber == 0) { // create Square   instance }
    if (myNumber == 1) { // create Triangle instance }

    return 0;
}
```

If this is confusing, I can try to elucidate. Thanks in advance!

Edit:

Really, I think I just need a pointer to a class without actually instantiating the class.

Comment: You can't do this in the way you're trying to. You could perhaps be a bit clever with templates and figure something out.

Comment: Although I know you're posting pseudo-code, keep in mind that you'll want to make your base class virtual so you can actually call methods on a base-class pointer and have them properly call methods of the derived classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want some kind of factory:

```
class Shape
{
public:
    Shape();
    static Shape* create(int id);
};

Shape* Shape::create(int id) {
  switch (id) {
    case 0: return new Square();
    case 1: return new Triangle();
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

Then when you want to create a particular `Shape` given user input, you can do:

```
int myNumber;
cin >> myNumber;
Shape* shape = Shape::create(myNumber);
```

This is it in it's simplest form. I would, however, recommend having the `create` function return a `std::unique_ptr<Shape>`, rather than a raw pointer. I would also set up static constants to represent the different IDs.

```
class Shape
{
public:
    Shape();
    static std::unique_ptr<Shape> create(int id);

    enum class Id { Square = 0, Triangle = 1 };
};

std::unique_ptr<Shape> Shape::create(Shape::Id id) {
  switch (id) {
    case Shape::Id::Square: return new Square();
    case Shape::Id::Triangle: return new Triangle();
  }
  return nullptr;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a `std::vector<Shape*>`  and then you can do `v.emplace_back(new Triangle());` in C++11. In C++03 you can use `v.push_back(new Triangle());`

You could use a raw array

```
Shape* shapes[10]; // array of pointers;

shapes[0] = new Triangle();
```

You could also go to use templates and create a template

```
template<typename ShapeType>
class Shape
{
 public:
     ShapeType draw(); 
     //All common Shape Operations
};

class Triangle
{
};

//C++11
using Triangle = Shape<Triangle>;
Triangle mytriangle;

//C++03
typedef Shape<Square> Square;
Square mysquare;
```

Comment: Tony, I'm implementing this on an Arduino and thus won't be able to use vectors.

Comment: @RyanTuck I put in a suggestion with templates or raw array of pointers

Comment: `Shape*[10] shapes` <- That's not valid C++ syntax. Also, it might be advisable to use `unique_ptr` rather than raw pointers. Managing memory manually is really non-trivial.

Comment: @phresnel I don't know if OP can use smart pointers, he's not a normal PC.  Fixed mistake.

Comment: He also said he can't use vectors, so unfortunately your answer practically goes down the drain :(

Comment: Tony, wouldn't using the raw array with `shapes[0] = new Triangle();` create all of those instances upon populating the array? Also, haven't heard of smart pointers before.

Comment: @RyanTuck that would create an instance that's at position 0 in the array.

Comment: @TonyTheLion, yes, that was what I was trying to avoid. Thank you for the input though!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<Shape*> shapes;

    cin << myNumber;

    // Depending on input, create instance of class corresponding to array index
    if (myNumber == 0) { shapes.push_back(new Square(); }
    if (myNumber == 1) { shapes.push_back(new Triangle(); }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This leaks. And for my stance on "Try-This" answer, you may want to look at my profile page.

Comment: Yes, it leaks - as with the original code, it is just an idea to get things moving.

Answer (score 1):

I would create this function:

```
Shape getNewShape(int shapeId)
{
    switch (shapeId)
    {
        case 1: return new Square();
        case 2: return new Triangle();
    }
    //here you should handle wrong shape id
}
```

then use it like that:

```
int main()
{
    cin << myNumber;

    // Depending on input, create instance of class corresponding to array index
    shape tempShape = getNewShape(myNumber);

    return 0;
}
```